# Is there a way to use the findIndex method from Data.Set with the current haskell platform?

Tags: haskell, extend, haskell-platform

I recently started working on some code which required the use of sets. So I went to Hoogle and searched for a existing solution, which I found in the module [Data.Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.1/docs/Data-Set.html). Unfortunately, Hoogle turned up the documentation for the Set included in the containers-0.5.3.1 package. This version contained the handy findIndex method, which I planned my program around.

But the Haskell platform only comes with containers-0.5.0.0, in which findIndex is not available. As I may only use the libraries coming with the Haskell platform, I am searching for a way to include this function or define it myself. Straight up copying the methods source code from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.1/docs/src/Data-Set.html obviously did not work. I hope you can help me find a solution to my problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suppose you need it to be _O_ (log _n_)? Otherwise, there's of course a trivial implementation with `toAscList`.

Comment: Have you been introduced to cabal sandboxes?  While it wouldn't solve your problem exactly, it should allow you to install whatever version of `containers` you like for each project.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sadly, yes I need O(log n).
bheklilr: No I have not been introduced to those. But as you said, they will not solve my problem as I need to use 0.5.0.0 conainers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `splitMember`:

```
lookupIndex :: (Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Maybe Int
lookupIndex x s
   | found      = Just $ size l
   | otherwise  = Nothing
 where (l, found, _) = splitMember x s
```